# Login and registration form on one page with Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

I have been stuck on this for a while. I am trying to put both the login and registration forms on the same page, however I have been getting multiple errors depending on which approach I try. The page is actually able to load fine, however neither of the form fields will load. And then when I hit the register or login button (both type submit), I most recently am getting a csrf related error. Any suggestions on how to implement both forms on the same page would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show your current code, you can disable the crsf middleware for the time-being for debugging.

Comment: Yep, also just stumbled onto this problem, with no other solution than disabling the protection altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be csrf token not found error.If you are using django 1.3 with csrf middleware you have to put csrf token **{% csrf_token %}** tag with each form posting data like this:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}

  {{ form.as_p }}

  <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I am using the csrf token properly, at least the way you described it, so unfortunately it is another problem. Do you know anyone who has successfully created a registration and login area on the same page using django?